# T-SQL Result Set - with 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

Here is my code :

```
drop table if exists #Table_A
drop table if exists #Table_B
drop table if exists #Table_C

create table #Table_A
(
    [DATE] Date,
    TYPE    INT,
    QTY     INT
);

create table #Table_B
(
    [DATE] Date,
    TYPE    INT,
    QTY     INT
);

create table #Table_C
(
    [DATE] Date,
    TYPE    INT,
    QTY     INT
);

Insert into #Table_A VALUES ('2018-01-01', 1, 10)
Insert into #Table_B VALUES ('2018-01-01', 1, 5)
Insert into #Table_B VALUES ('2018-01-01', 2, 10)
Insert into #Table_B VALUES ('2018-01-01', 3, 10)
Insert into #Table_C VALUES ('2018-01-01', 1, 5)
Insert into #Table_C VALUES ('2018-01-01', 2, 10)
Insert into #Table_C VALUES ('2018-01-01', 3, 10)
```

Query :

```
select 
    A.[DATE], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.[TYPE] = 1 THEN A.QTY END)  A_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B.[TYPE] = 1 THEN B.QTY END)  B_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN C.[TYPE] = 1 THEN C.QTY END)  C_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.[TYPE] = 2 THEN A.QTY END)  A_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B.[TYPE] = 2 THEN B.QTY END)  B_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN C.[TYPE] = 2 THEN C.QTY END)  C_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.[TYPE] = 3 THEN A.QTY END)  A_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B.[TYPE] = 3 THEN B.QTY END)  B_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN C.[TYPE] = 3 THEN C.QTY END)  C_QTY
FROM 
    #Table_A A 
    INNER JOIN #Table_B B ON A.DATE = B.DATE AND A.TYPE = B.TYPE
    INNER JOIN #Table_C C ON A.DATE = C.DATE AND A.TYPE = C.TYPE
GROUP BY A.[DATE]
```

Current Result:

```
DATE        |   A_QTY   |   B_QTY   |   C_QTY   A_QTY   B_QTY   C_QTY   A_QTY   B_QTY   C_QTY
2018-01-01  |   10      |   5       |   5       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

**Expected Result:**

```
DATE        |   A_QTY   |   B_QTY   |   C_QTY   A_QTY   B_QTY   C_QTY   A_QTY   B_QTY   C_QTY    
2018-01-01  |   10      |   5       |   5       NULL    10      10      NULL    10      10
```

Please let me know how I can get expected result. (I know currently its not working because of `inner join`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is that, since it uses `INNER JOIN`s, only records/date tuples that exists in all 3 tables are counted in.

If there is a table that can will *always* have all (`TYPE`, `DATE`) tuples available (in your sample data, that would be `Table_C`), then you can use it a starting point and use `LEFT JOIN`s :

```
FROM #Table_C C 
LEFT JOIN #Table_A A ON A.DATE = C.DATE AND A.TYPE = C.TYPE
LEFT JOIN #Table_B B ON B.DATE = C.DATE AND B.TYPE = C.TYPE
```

Else, you probably want to change your `INNER JOIN`s to `FULL OUTER JOIN`s :

```
FROM #Table_A A 
FULL OUTER JOIN #Table_B B ON A.DATE = B.DATE AND A.TYPE = B.TYPE
FULL OUTER JOIN #Table_C C ON A.DATE = C.DATE AND A.TYPE = C.TYPE
```

The `FULL OUTER JOIN` solution requires to adapt the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses, since the date could come from any of the 3 tables.

Query :

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(A.[DATE], B.[DATE], C.[DATE]) DATE,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.[TYPE] = 1 THEN A.QTY END)  A_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B.[TYPE] = 1 THEN B.QTY END)  B_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN C.[TYPE] = 1 THEN C.QTY END)  C_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.[TYPE] = 2 THEN A.QTY END)  A_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B.[TYPE] = 2 THEN B.QTY END)  B_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN C.[TYPE] = 2 THEN C.QTY END)  C_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.[TYPE] = 3 THEN A.QTY END)  A_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B.[TYPE] = 3 THEN B.QTY END)  B_QTY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN C.[TYPE] = 3 THEN C.QTY END)  C_QTY
FROM 
    #Table_A A 
    FULL OUTER JOIN #Table_B B ON A.DATE = B.DATE AND A.TYPE = B.TYPE
    FULL OUTER JOIN #Table_C C ON A.DATE = C.DATE AND A.TYPE = C.TYPE
GROUP BY COALESCE(A.[DATE], B.[DATE], C.[DATE])
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=19f1c49c79a63d0645c495040094e5b7)** returns :

```
DATE                | A_QTY | B_QTY | C_QTY | A_QTY | B_QTY | C_QTY | A_QTY | B_QTY | C_QTY
:------------------ | ----: | ----: | ----: | ----: | ----: | ----: | ----: | ----: | ----:
01/01/2018 00:00:00 |    10 |     5 |     5 |       |    10 |    10 |       |    10 |    10
```